# Load .m4a file from disk into NSData object - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, avaudiorecorder, m4a

I recorded the users voice with an `AVAudioRecorder` and saved it as a .m4a file in the documents folder. When I am trying to load the .m4a file into an `NSData`object, the object is nil.
The .m4a file contains sound and the used file path is correct.
I am using the following line to load the .m4a file:

```
let soundData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(soundPath)
println("\(soundData)") // prints nil
```

Comment: Did you try checking if the file exists using `fileExistsAtPath`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath:

Comment: I did not use that method to check its existence, I used iTunesFilesharing to inspect it. So the file exists and has a size of around 180KB and a length of 6 seconds.

Comment: The paths to the file are exactly the same, I logged them to the console to test it. The method `fileExistsAtPath` returns false, but in the iTunesFilesharing panel the .m4a file always appears and is playable. Maybe I am using the wrong method to load the .m4a file inside a NSData object?

Comment: Since: "The method fileExistsAtPath returns false" and `NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(soundPath)` returns nil there are only a couple of possibilities: 1. The file does not exist. 2. The file does not exist where you think it does.  3. The path is incorrect. 4. Apple's code has an error no one has noticed. As for "iTunesFilesharing" that indicates there is a file sonewhere that plays. The best thing to check is in Xcode: Windows:Devices. Select the device connected to ther computer, double click the app, Examine the file contents.

Comment: I expected the files within Xcode, so I think it is the 4th case, Apple´s code has an error. Is there another way to load that file into an `NSData`object?

Comment: I rather doubt the Apple error but there will probably be Beta6 today. See my answer for another way to load data. I would be more inpressed if you logged each and copy/pasted them to the question. For some reason it is common for those who ask questions no to provide full information. You are aware that the iOS file system case sensitive?

Comment: I already used your second method, see my comment for the result.

Comment: There is also `NSFileHandle` and the method: `readDataToEndOfFile `.

Comment: Using `NSFileHandle` and `readDataToEndOfFile` it finally works!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the AVAudioPlayer requires a path with a "file://" prefix, while SFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath() needs this prefix removed from the path in order to work properly.  Try removing this by doing something like:

```
soundPath = soundPath.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: "If path specifies a directory, or if some other error occurs, this method returns nil."

The The best way to check for the file is in Xcode: Menu Windows:Devices. Select the device connected to the computer, double click the app, Examine the file contents.

println("sound path: (soundPath)"), bets are it is not correct.

Consider using the `NSData` method, it has an error parameter to better report a failure:

```
+ (id)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

Example with error reporting:

```
let error:NSError
let soundData = NSData().contentsOfFile: soundPath options: 0 error: &errorPtr)
if soundData != nil {
    // Do something
}
else {
    println("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Example error message:

> error: The file “TestSound.m4a” couldn’t be opened because there is no
>   such file.

BTW, a more clear name for the path: sound might be soundPath.

Comment: The error message you have written there is the one I get, but I did not know why I am getting this error. I am creating the file with an `AVAudioRecorder` and then passing the path to another class, so the paths are exactly the same, even when logging them to the console and comparing them. Furthermore the file appears in the iTunesFilesharing panel and contains the recorded sound. Another interesting fact is, that I can play the sound with an `AVAudioPlayer`, so there must be a file at this path.

Answer (score 0):

Release the AVAudioRecorder before trying to load the url to NSData.